# Enable/disable submit button when any/no checkbox in form is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I am trying to use jQuery to dynamically enable/disable a submit button for a form.

The HTML:

```
<form id="user-add-to-group">
  <table class="group-list">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th>Voornaam</th>
        <th>Achternaam</th>
        <th>S/P-nummer</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Type</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>   
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Surname</td>
        <td>No.</td>
        <td>email@bs.com</td>
        <td>student</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="user_add_to_group[]" value="75F0CE8F-4B6F-4E17-BC7B-0B06AAD84625"></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <button disabled="disabled" type="button" id="participant_add_btn" name="participant_add_btn" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>                            
</form>
```

And the jQuery:

```
$('table.group-list tr').on("click", function(){
  $(this).find("input[type=checkbox]").trigger('click');
    if($("#user-add-to-group input[type=checkbox]:checked").length>0){
      $("#participant_add_btn").prop("disabled","false");
    }
    else {
      $("#participant_add_btn").prop("disabled","disabled");
    }
});
```

I want to make the entire table row clickable, so the jQuery triggers a click event when the tr is clicked. This works, but I cannot seem to figure out why my button won't be enabled afterwards. I want to enable it when any checkbox within the form is checked, and disable it when none of them are.

If more info is needed, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `jQuery.prop` expects value to be `Boolean`, any `string` which is not empty is considred as `true` as it is truthy value

```js
$('table.group-list tr').on("click", function() {
  $(this).find("input[type=checkbox]").trigger('click');
  $("#participant_add_btn").prop("disabled", !$("#user-add-to-group input[type=checkbox]:checked").length);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="user-add-to-group">
  <table class="group-list">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th>Voornaam</th>
        <th>Achternaam</th>
        <th>S/P-nummer</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Type</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Surname</td>
        <td>No.</td>
        <td>email@bs.com</td>
        <td>student</td>
        <td>
          <input type="checkbox" name="user_add_to_group[]" value="75F0CE8F-4B6F-4E17-BC7B-0B06AAD84625">
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <button disabled="disabled" type="button" id="participant_add_btn" name="participant_add_btn" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Accepted for most efficient code. Elegant. Thank you!

Comment: @LennartKloppenburg Happy to help!

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass Boolean argument instead of string while setting the property value.

```
$('#participant_add_btn').prop('disabled', false);
```

or use `.removeAttr("disabled")`

```
$('#participant_add_btn').removeAttr("disabled");
```

Your code will not work on click of checkbox. For that,you need to check the target of clicked element, if it is already checkbox then do not trigger the click event for it:

**Working Snippet:**

```js
$('table.group-list tr').on("click", function(e){
  if($(e.target).is(':not(:checkbox)'))
   $(this).find("input[type=checkbox]").trigger('click');
   $("#participant_add_btn").prop("disabled",$("#user-add-to-group input[type=checkbox]:checked").length == 0);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="user-add-to-group">
  <table class="group-list">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th>Voornaam</th>
        <th>Achternaam</th>
        <th>S/P-nummer</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Type</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>   
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Surname</td>
        <td>No.</td>
        <td>email@bs.com</td>
        <td>student</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="user_add_to_group[]" value="75F0CE8F-4B6F-4E17-BC7B-0B06AAD84625"></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <button disabled="disabled" type="button" id="participant_add_btn" name="participant_add_btn" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>                            
</form>
```

Comment: Play with the `Boolean(true)` instead of `"disabled"`

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#toggle').click(function () {
//check if checkbox is checked
if ($(this).is(':checked')) {

    $('#sendNewSms').removeAttr('disabled'); //enable input

} else {
    $('#sendNewSms').attr('disabled', true); //disable input
}
```

});

[**Check here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/T6hvz/)